# In WPaint how do we change the color from yellow to red by using the Jquery

Tags: jquery

We are creating an application that requires: In WPaint how do we change the color from yellow to red by using the Jquery. So we did some hit and trial but didn't found any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

While creating object of wpaint try to use "fillStyle" for inner color and "strokeStyle" for border color like :

```
    $('#wPaint').wPaint({
      path: '/wPaint-master/', 
      image: '/wPaint-master/demo/img/forkme_right_darkblue.png', 
      mode: 'Rectangle',
      fillStyle: 'transparent', 
      strokeStyle: '#ff0000',
      lineWidth: '1',
      menuHandle: false, 
      menuOffsetLeft: -35,
      menuOffsetTop: -50
    });
```